# Drop-in replacement for "select" element?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I need to control a `<select>` element (open it, navigate through its options, select value etc) using javascript.

As this is impossible(JS cannot open a `<select>` element)  I wonder: Is there a drop-in replacement that looks the same(keeps the native UA styling of a real select element) and works the same(i.e. in forms, keyboard navigation (up/down) ), except it can be controlled more by JS ?

More background:
 I have an ElectronJS based application and until now I used native OS keyboard events to control the `<select>` element but since the latest update of the OS( Mac Mojave) native keyboard events are no longer allowed so I have to use JS only. The app is quite big so I'm trying to minimise the amount of work to replace native `<select>` menu with a custom one.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value of a select input, then you can do that using vanilla javascript.
Given a select element like this:

```
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can use the following javascript to change the value:

```
document.getElementById('my-select').value = 'saab'
```

```html
<select id="test-select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('test-select').value = 'fiat'">Click me</Button>
```

Comment: I need to open the select menu and navigate through the options using javascript. I'm developing a TV application so the navigation must be done remotely (with JS) not with the keyboard or mouse.

Answer (score 0):

you can use select2 library
https://select2.org/
with search